# Parser is not encoding string correctly

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, ibm-integration-bus

Text I'm trying to get:

```
przełącznica
```

This is what I actually have (browser might now view it properly - there are two squares instead of "łą"):

```
przecznica
```

---

BLOB:

```
70 72 7A 65 C5 82 C4 85 63 7A 6E 69 63 61
```

**EDIT:** This is what I get from parser

```
70 72 7A 65 1A 1A 63 7A 6E 69 63 61
```

---

ESQL used to parse BLOB:

```sql
DECLARE blobMsg BLOB InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB ;
         CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.inpMsg DOMAIN ('XMLNSC') NAME 'XMLNSC';
         CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.inpMsg.XMLNSC PARSE(blobMsg OPTIONS FolderBitStream CCSID 1208 FORMAT 'XMLNSC');
```

I have tried CCSIDs: 1208 (UTF8), 912 (ISO-8859-2), 1200(UTF16 I guess):
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/nls/rbagsccsidcdepgscharsets.htm

EDIT: Working code:

```
DECLARE blobMsg BLOB InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB;
DECLARE remove BLOB X'EFBBBF';
DECLARE message BLOB REPLACE(InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB, remove, CAST('' AS BLOB));
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.inpMsg DOMAIN ('XMLNSC') NAME 'XMLNSC';
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.inpMsg.XMLNSC PARSE(message OPTIONS FolderBitStream CCSID 05348 FORMAT 'XMLNSC');
```

Comment: Please supply the input document as an XML document _and_ as a sequence of bytes. Please also tell us which CCSID (text encoding) the source application used when it created the XML document. Without the correct CCSID, the input BLOB cannot be reliably interpreted.

Comment: @filemono can you add the Input BLOB as hex pairs.

Comment: @filemono not that the characters X'EFBBBF" should appear other than at the front of the Input BLOB I'd still suggest using SUBSTRING with AFTER. DECLARE message BLOB SUBSTRING(blobMsg AFTER remove);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly **przełącznica** by itself is not valid XML and so you'll get an exception when you try to invoke the XMLNSC parser using the code you have outlined. You need to do a CAST instead.

I generated a little test Application/MsgFlow in IIB 10 to illustrate CASTing the BLOB.

[image: Simple Encoding App]

The code in ConvertAndParse is

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE ConvertAndParse
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    DECLARE blobMsg BLOB X'70727A65C582C485637A6E696361';
    CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.inpMsg DOMAIN 'XMLNSC';
    CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.inpMsg.XMLNSC NAME 'AsUtf8' VALUE CAST(blobMsg AS CHAR CCSID 1208);

    CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'XMLNSC';
    CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC.EncodingResponse NAME 'AsUtf8InTag' VALUE CAST(blobMsg AS CHAR CCSID 1208);
    CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC.EncodingResponse NAME CAST(blobMsg AS CHAR CCSID 1208) VALUE 'As a tag name';

    RETURN TRUE;
END;
END MODULE;
```

When I run a debug session the value put into the LocalEnvironment tree looks like.

[image: Debug Values]

And the result of invoking the flow from a browser.

[image: Browser Result]

Now let's deal with the which encoding we are looking at. Looking at what I assume is the input BLOB let's see if the BLOB matches up with UTF-8.

```
70 72 7A 65 C5 82 C4 85 63 7A 6E 69 63 61
```

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable width character encoding that sets the high order bit to indicate two or more bytes. We also want a page that shows the common code points for UTF-8 [Complete Character List for UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm). Note it's not actually complete.

Looking at the first 4 bytes none of them have the high order bit on

```
70 72 7A 65
```

And the aforementioned Character List says that's **prze**, so far so good.

Then we hit C8 which has the high order bit on. Doing a bit of visual parsing we get two sets of **probable** two byte character pairs

```
C5 82
C4 85
```

Referring to the Character List our two candidate pairs do in fact match the two characters we want and the next six characters which do not have their high order bits on translate to **cznica**. Looking really good.

Now to eliminate the other candidate encodings, if we can.

[UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) uses 2 or 4 bytes to represent each character depending on the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) with **prze** encoded as

```
UTF-16BE - CP 1200 - 00 70 00 72 00 7A 00 65
UTF-16LE - CP 1202 - 70 00 72 00 7A 00 65 00
```

Given that there are not lots and lots of null characters **00** it is reasonable to discount UTF-16.

ISO-8859-2 - [CP 912](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Code_page_912) is a single byte character set and the **C5** and **C4** code points do not match the two desired characters and thus we can eliminate it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it explains a lot!. Unfortunately, PARSE with CSSID 1208 didn't work. It worked with 5348 code which is Windows 1 Latin. It should work with 1208 especially when I cast my BLOB from 1208 and cut BOM signature (new version of the flow receives utf-8bom encoded message). I edited my question with the code that is working.

Comment: @filemono You are welcome and thanks for the updates to the original question